# Where is erlang dbg module gone on rebar3 build?

Tags: erlang, rebar, dbg, jiffy

when running `rebar3 compile`, then `./_build/default/rel/api/bin/api console`,

then in erlang shell trying to use `dbg` I get.

`m(dbg).
** exception error: undefined function dbg:module_info/0
     in function  c:m/1 (c.erl, line 508)`

Any clue how to resolve? what am I doing wrong? the only thing I did after `rebar3 new release api` and adding some basic functionality is apply an overlay for jiffy to compile right.

(running `erl` I do have the `dbg` module)

any suggestions?

Thanks!

---

Comment below by legoscia works just fine! just add to relx config in `rebar.config`. Thanks!

Comment: To access `dbg`, you need to explicitly include the `runtime_tools` application in your release. It's part of Erlang/OTP, but not included by default in releases created by rebar.